# how to set list of data into session context?

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to store list of data into session object. My scenario is I have one gridview control inside a page. below of the gridview have two text boxes and button. When i press button than gridview will have filled with text boxes value. Every time my pressing on button it will add new row into gridview to show entered data..So, for that i have to use session context. But my issue is how to store two textboxes value into session and how to read it again..
I dont want to use temporary sql database table.

So if anyone knows about it than please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
Use this code on the click event of button

```
if(Session["value1"] == null)
{
    Session["value1"] = new List<String>();
}
((List<String>)Session["value1"]).Add(testbox1.value);
```

To output the data you can loop through all the values :

```
    List<String> V = (List<String>) Session["value1"];
     for(int j = 0 ; j < V.Count ; j++)
     {
       String str = V[j];
       //ADD str TO GRID VIEW.....
     }
```

The same code goes for textbox2.

Comment: It works...But should I do it for each textbox?? In this case i have to define two sessions right?? but what if i want to use only one session

Comment: Thanx man...It was so simple...I have done it with creating a class. I have created two properties in it and my problem solved....Thanks a lot.... :)

Comment: Yes , we are friends now. Which city?

Comment: Thanx to be my frind...m from Baroda...nd u?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13599/discussion-between-ravi-jain-and-user968441)